# Vercel deployment with next.js is blank, but works on local host

Tags: css, next.js, deployment, tailwind-css, vercel

sorry i am extremely lost as to why this is happening, there are no errors on the logs or anything either. when i open the deployment, my app is there for a split second then it goes to blank. i think the issue is to do with my navigation. please help me, have been struggling for a long time trying different things

here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "nextjs",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^14.1.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.1.3",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

my layout.tsx:

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <div className="flex h-screen flex-col md:flex-row md:overflow-hidden">
      <div className="w-full flex-none md:w-48">
        <SideNav />
      </div>
      <div className="flex-grow md:overflow-y-auto">{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

my sidenav:

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import Image from 'next/image';
import NavLinks from '@/app/ui/dashboard/nav-links';

export default function SideNav() {
  return (
    <div className="flex h-screen flex-col w-48 bg-[#091928] p-2.5 text-white" >
      <div className="flex items-center mb-6 p-1.5 space-x-2" style={{ marginTop: '7px' }}>
        <Image src="/clerkie.svg" alt="Clerkie Challenge" width={15} height={15} />
        <h1 className="text-xs font-bold">Clerkie Challenge</h1>
      </div>
      <NavLinks/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

my navlinks:

```
'use client';

import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation';
import Link from 'next/link';
import Image from 'next/image';

const links = [
  { name: 'Home', href: '/', icon: '/home.svg' }, 
  { name: 'Friends', href: '/friends', icon: '/friends.svg' },
];

export default function NavLinks() {
  const pathname = usePathname();

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col">
      {links.map((link) => {
        const isActive = pathname === link.href;
        let className = 'flex h-[32px] items-center justify-start gap-2 rounded-md p-2 text-xs font-medium transition-colors w-full';

        if (isActive) {
          className += ' bg-[424242] text-white';
        } else {
          className += ' bg-[#091928] text-white';
        }

        return (
          <Link key={link.name} href={link.href}>
            <div className={className}>
              <Image src={link.icon} alt={`${link.name} icon`} width={18} height={18} />
              <span>{link.name}</span>
            </div>
          </Link>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

an image of the directory rn:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iENiK.png)

i thought the website would successfully deploy on vercel, but instead it is just a blank page (though sometimes it appears for a split second when you first click into the website before disappearing)